# preg_match: Unknown modifier '+'?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have this pattern to check emails :

```
$emailpat = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
```

When i want to execute this code:

```
$emailpat = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
if(!preg_match($emailpat, $_POST["email"])){
    echo "error in email";
}else{
    echo "done";
}
```

i get the following error:

```
preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '+'
```

Comment: I don't see any delimiters!

Comment: This-> http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php The ground and the basic of every regex

Comment: you think this was the problem?

Comment: Yes?! Every regex needs delimiters

Comment: i add them like this :
"/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/"
i get the following error:
preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '='

Comment: Not directly to your answser but maybe this help you to validate email:
`preg_match('/^[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^`{}|~_-]+[.a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^`{}|~_-]*@[a-z0-9]+[._a-z0-9-]*\.[a-z0-9]+$/ui', $email);`

Answer (score 1):

#### Recommendation

If you're handling user-input, i recommend the [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function. It does pretty much the same thing, but without the whole regular expression stuff.

#### Examples

- [Filter Validation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php)
- [Filter Sanitization](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php)

#### References

- [PHP Manual - Data Filtering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

thank for help !! the problem was the determin ...

```
pattern /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
        ^               ^                                ^                                                                                    ^ 
        |               |                                |                                                                                    |
      start            END                             start                                                                                 END
```

i need to mask the slashes with 2 backslash

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
```